# Mongoengine + Django-tables2: Expected table or queryset, not QuerySet

Tags: python, django, mongoengine, django-tables2

I'm starting to learn django and using it to build and interface to our mongoDB using also mongoengine.
I'm following [this tutorial](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/tutorial.html) to use django-tables2 but I can't even start it because I get the error `Expected table or queryset, not QuerySet`.
This is the class I'm using:

```
class Companies(Document):
    url = StringField(required=True, unique=True)
    name = StringField(required=True)
    founded = IntField()
    headquarters = EmbeddedDocumentField(HQ)
    description = StringField()
```

On the view I'm just doing

```
def companies(request):
    return render(request, 'toolbox/companies.html', {'companies': Companies.objects.all()})
```

I see that mongoengine output is a QuerySet type. How can I convert it to some type I can input on django-tables?
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The data format django-tables2 expects is a QuerySet, a list of dicts, or something behaving like that. You can create a class inheriting from [`TableData`](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/master/django_tables2/data.py#L6), pass that to a vanilla `django_tables2.Table` and put that in your context instead of `Companies.objects.all()`.

It would look somewhat like this:

```
import django_tables2 as tables
from django_tables2.data import TableQuerysetData


class TableDocumentData(TableQuerysetData):
    # not sure what to override here, since I do not know the mongoengine API at all


def companies(request):
    table = CompanyTable(data=TableDocumentData(Companies.objects.all()))

    return render(request, 'toolbox/companies.html', {'companies': table})
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! I'm searching for information about TableData and TableQuerysetData in order to find out how to create the TableDocumentData.
Just a silly question, what's the CompanyTable on your example? It's the normal "tables.Table" one?

Comment: Yes, there are some omissions. I'll try to address this when I have time, if you manage to figure it out in the meantime, consider adding answer to your own question